# rosws info gives me error 'VcsClient' object has no attribute 'url_matches'

Tags: ros, python, rosws, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to use rosws to manage my workspace and .rosinstall file. I used rosws merge and rosws set to create the file, and rosws update to grab all the packages from their various repositories. now when I run rosws info I am getting all these errors that look like this:

```
Error processing 'rtt_geometry' : 'VcsClient' object has no attribute 'url_matches'
```

The python stack trace looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.6.19-py2.7.egg/rosinstall/common.py", line 252, in run
    result_dict = self.worker.do_work()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.6.19-py2.7.egg/rosinstall/multiproject_cmd.py", line 373, in do_work
    path_spec = self.element.get_versioned_path_spec()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.6.19-py2.7.egg/rosinstall/config_elements.py", line 378, in get_versioned_path_spec
    if self._get_vcsc().url_matches(curr_uri, uri):
AttributeError: 'VcsClient' object has no attribute 'url_matches'
```

and my .rosinstall file looks like:

```
# THIS IS A FILE WHICH IS MODIFIED BY rosinstall
# IT IS UNLIKELY YOU WANT TO EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND,
# UNLESS FOR REMOVING ENTRIES.
# IF YOU WANT TO CHANGE THE ROS ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
# USE THE rosinstall TOOL INSTEAD.
# IF YOU CHANGE IT, USE rosinstall FOR THE CHANGES TO TAKE EFFECT
- other: {local-name: /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros}
- other: {local-name: /opt/ros/fuerte/share}
- other: {local-name: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks}
- setup-file: {local-name: /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.sh}
- svn: {local-name: biorob_common, uri: 'https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/biorob_common'}
- git: {local-name: falkor_quadrotor, uri: 'https://github.com/FalkorSystems/falkor_quadrotor.git'}
- git: {local-name: hector_common, uri: 'https://github.com/FalkorSystems/hector_common.git'}
- svn: {local-name: hector_gazebo, uri: 'https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/fuerte/hector_gazebo'}
- git: {local-name: hector_localization, uri: 'https://github.com/FalkorSystems/hector_localization.git'}
- svn: {local-name: hector_models, uri: 'https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/fuerte/hector_models'}
- svn: {local-name: hector_navigation, uri: 'http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_navigation'}
- svn: {local-name: hector_nist_arenas_gazebo, uri: 'https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_nist_arenas_gazebo'}
- svn: {local-name: hector_quadrotor, uri: 'https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/fuerte/hector_quadrotor'}
- svn: {local-name: hector_quadrotor_apps, uri: 'http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_quadrotor_apps'}
- svn: {local-name: hector_quadrotor_experimental, uri: 'https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_quadrotor_experimental'}
- svn: {local-name: hector_sandbox, uri: 'http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_sandbox'}
- svn: {local-name: hector_slam, uri: 'https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/fuerte/hector_slam'}
- svn: {local-name: hector_turtlebot, uri: 'http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_turtlebot'}
- svn: {local-name: hector_ugv_common, uri: 'https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_ugv_common'}
- svn: {local-name: hector_worldmodel, uri: 'http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_worldmodel'}
- git:
    local-name: imu_tools
    meta: {repo-name: ccny-ros-pkg}
    uri: https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools.git
- git:
    local-name: mav_tools
    meta: {repo-name: ccny-ros-pkg}
    uri: https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/mav_tools.git
- git:
    local-name: orocos_toolchain
    meta: {repo-name: kul-ros-pkg}
    uri: http://git.gitorious.org/orocos-toolchain/orocos_toolchain.git
    version: master
- git:
    local-name: rtt_common_msgs
    meta: {repo-name: kul-ros-pkg}
    uri: http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/rtt_common_msgs.git
    version: master
- git:
    local-name: rtt_geometry
    meta: {repo-name: kul-ros-pkg}
    uri: http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/rtt_geometry.git
    version: master
- git:
    local-name: rtt_ros_comm
    meta: {repo-name: kul-ros-pkg}
    uri: http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/rtt_ros_comm.git
    version: master
- git:
    local-name: rtt_ros_integration
    meta: {repo-name: kul-ros-pkg}
    uri: http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/robotics/rtt_ros_integration.git
    version: master
- hg:
    local-name: eigen
    meta: {repo-name: wg-kforge}
    uri: https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/eigen
    version: tf_rework
- git: {local-name: ardrone_autonomy, uri: 'https://github.com/FalkorSystems/ardrone_autonomy.git'}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45201/rosws-info-gives-me-error-%27vcsclient%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27url_matches%27/) by [sameer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3158/sameer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2012-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That sounds like you have a newer version of rosinstall on your system than vcstools.  Please make sure both vcstools and rosinstall are up to date.

If you are on ubuntu I suggest uninstalling any pip based installation and using apt-get install python-rosinstall python-vcstools

Otherwise use the -U option to pip to update.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sameer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3158/sameer/) on 2012-10-08**:
Thanks, that did it!